# Sed the middle of string with two conditions

Tags: regex, sed, grep

How can i take sed with 2 condition in just 1 single command, and, is there anything else better than this solution, i want to take then name of latest version geckodriver, so i doing this

`curl -s https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest`

the output of this is

`<html><body>You are being <a href="https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0">redirected</a>.</body></html>`

i want to take only this output

`v0.26.0`

so i am using sed

`curl -s https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/latest | sed 's/.*tag[/]//'`

and the output is

`v0.26.0">redirected</a>.</body></html>`

How can i take only **v0.26.0**

i can't use awk. thank you for your advince.

Comment: In your approach, `sed 's/.*tag[/]//; s/".*//'` would do the job.

Comment: Why can't you use awk? It's a standard UNIX tool just like sed and grep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -n 's~.*/tag/\([^"]*\).*~\1~p'
```

Here,

- `-n` suppresses default line output
- `.*/tag/\([^"]*\).*` matches

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars
  - `/tag/`  - `/tag/` text
  - `\([^"]*\)`  - captures into Group 1 any 0 or more chars other than `"`
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `\1` keeps the value of Group 1 in the result
- `p` prints the result.

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/vIWuY4):

```
#!/bin/bash
s='<html><body>You are being <a href="https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0">redirected</a>.</body></html>'
sed -n 's~.*/tag/\([^"]*\).*~\1~p' <<< "$s"
# => v0.26.0
```